# javascript regex replace all tab new line repeating to single new line

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Tried to use javascript regex replace all tab new line repeating to single new line. Use some online tester shown it works. But it not in javascript. Can someone help

```
var str;
str.replace(/[\t \n,]+/, ",");

input: UIPLAT-234 UIPLAT-342,UIPLAT-3452<\t>UIPLAT-23<\n>UIPLAT-55
the above <\t> and <\n> represent the input of a tab and new line
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Are you looking to replace tabs and newline characters? Or are you trying to replace the latter where 2 instances of either are back to back such as `\n\n` or `\t\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the global flag:

```
str.replace(/[\t \n,]+/g, ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function returns new string, so you need to assign it:

```
var str = "UIPLAT-234 UIPLAT-342,UIPLAT-3452\tUIPLAT-23\nUIPLAT-55";
newString = str.replace(/[\t \n,]+/g, ",");

console.log(newString);
```